# Inserting a second cell with value using 1st cell's value, third cell value with sum of 1st and second cell value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The real scenario is a bit complicated so, i will explain in a simple way.

I have a table with 10 columns as below

```
ID     Year1   Year2   Year3   Year4   Year5
--------------------------------------------
1       x1      x1+     x1+      x1+
              Year1    Year1+   Year1+   and so on
                       Year2    Year2+
                                Year3
```

x1 is a scalar value

Year1 - previous cell's value for the 'same row'

In such a case, how do i write insert statement in sql server.

I cannot use Insert into tableName values (1, x1, ???.....

I get stuck from the third row onwards. Any help would be help ful. Thank you.

Another option i found was to first insert, and then sequencially update for each cell's value. This method uses too many lines of code and I fear it could lead to overhead

Comment: Is `x1` really the same value in all the expressions or did you mean `x1`, `x2`, `x3` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions here.

1. If you use T-SQL then use variables for columns and update these values as you described before triggering an Insert.
2. If you use some kind of middle-ware programming language like Java, update the column values before inserting.

Comment: Ok thanks. Your first option was what I used first inserting and the rest, updating.